# Why can't I enable forms authentication on IIS7 (windows server 2008)

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, forms-authentication, windows-server-2008

I'm completely new to IIS7 and windows server 2008.  To setup the context of what I'm doing: I'm having to migrate a classic ASP web app from Windows Server 2000 (IIS6) to Windows Server 2008 (IIS7).  The classic ASP app uses forms authentication to restrict page access by usernames and roles defined on my SQL server DB.

As I configured my website on IIS7... I found that there was no option for Forms authentication, only anonymous.  [Per this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/zroiy/archive/2008/08/17/missing-windows-authentication-provider-for-iis-7-on-windows-server-2008.aspx), I added all available additional "security" and "application development" role services from Server Manager expecting that forms authentication would then be available.  I would post screenshots...but can't yet as I'm a new user.  Anyway... this gave me 3 new authentication types:

1. Basic Auth
2. Digest Auth
3. Windows Auth

...but forms authentication is still not available.

Beyond this, I also attempted to enable forms authentication [per this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771077%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) both using both these commands:

- appcmd set config /commit:WEBROOT /section:system.web/authentication /mode:Forms
- appcmd set config /commit: /section:system.web/authentication /mode:Forms

I realize (or I believe) that the first command implies I'm using .Net to enforce security... which I'm not (yet).  In any case, both of these executed successfully... but neither enabled Forms authentication.

It may be that it's not even possible to enable forms authentication in IIS7 on windows server 2008 for a purely ASP classic site but the screenshots at the first link I posted seem to indicate I should be able to enable it.  I'm wondering if I'm going to have to create an asp.net site in order to enable forms authentication... and then configure asp.net to govern security for files w/ the *.asp (classic ASP) file type.  Anyone have any insight for me?  This is so frustrating.

Comment: The solution is to select and install ASP.Net components in the IIS Server Role Services.

Answer (score 0):

Forms authentication is effectively "anonymous" since your application is responsible for authentication and is not relying on the Windows auth mechanism in any way. Is there something I'm missing here? Is this app a canned app or something you're coding?